# How to check whether the specific file is uploaded to database or not using symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am creating  a job portal and there I want to check  when job seeker applying for a job before he uploading his CV , check whether he is upload his CV inside his profile or not. When jobseeker upload a CV while creating a profile the CV status will be change into '1' else '0'. so I want to check it inside my vacancyApply action. How can I do this?

Comment: $this->vacancy = $this->getVacancyManagementService()->getVacancyById($vacancy_id);
            $this->getUser()->setAttribute('referer_url','@apply_vacancy');

            if($request->isMethod('POST'))
            {
                $this->logMessage("=====request is POST");

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
public function executeVacancyApply(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  if ($this->getUser()->getCVStatus()) // pretending cv_status is a boolean
  {
    // he does
  }
  else
  {
    // he doesn't
  }
}
```

Comment: ok, inside my model, i create dao class like this ------------------------      public function getJobseekerById($user_id){
        try
                   {
                       $jobseeker_table=Doctrine_core::getTable('Jobseeker');
                       $jobseeker = $jobseeker_table->findByUserId($user_id);
                       return $jobseeker;
                   }
                   catch(Exception $ex)
                   {
                       throw new DaoException($ex->getMessage());
                   }


    }

Comment: and this is my contrller actionclass

Comment: $user_session=sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
            $logged_user = $this->logged_user=$user_session->getAttribute('logged_user');
            $user_id = $logged_user->getUserId();
            if($user_id){

                $this->jobseeker = $this->getUserManagementService()->getJobseekerById($user_id);
          $this->getUserManagementService()->getJobseekerById($user_id);
                if ($this->getUser()->getCvstatus()){
                    $this->redirect('vacancy/thankyou');
                }else
                {$this->redirect('vacancy/applyVacancy');
                }

Comment: what i did was i checked the user_session and then get the user id, and from tht foind the jobseeker id and , through tht i want to check whether cvstatus true or false ..

Comment: First, what I showed you didn't work? - Also, can you please use Gist to host code? It's unreadable when you paste is as a comment.